# set load user profile to true for cryptographic exception but it is writing logs in AppData

Tags: .net, vb.net, iis-7.5, x509certificate, cryptographicexception

I have a WCF service which in turn calls other service and uses .p12 key for verification. I have set Load User Profile in Application pool to true to handle "CryptographicException was unhandled: System cannot find the specified file" exception. After this change, each service call is writing logs to below path - C:\Users\AppPool\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA. Can anyone please help how to eliminate writing logs to specified path.

PS: - Previously service used to work with Load User Profile to false and there were no logs writing to path. This has happened after setting Load User Profile to TRUE in AppPool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have a WCF service which in turn calls other service and uses .p12 key for verification". That's interesting. Why does it require user profile load? Do you have a reference link?

Comment: @LexLi we place .p12 keys in a folder where path is specified in config file. Unless we set Load user profile to true, we get this exception "CryptographicException was unhandled: System cannot find the specified file".